# React Error Boundaries cannot work, just break

Tags: reactjs

I copy the example from codepen to stackblitz, but something go wrong.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7tynfg

This has already perplexed me for a long time.

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement. 'Go wrong' and 'cannot work' don't really explain anything. All relevant code should be presented in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specific to how errors are handled in React development mode. They are propagated to global `error` handler for easier debugging, while current setup may be responsible for showing an error received from global `error` handler in DOM.

In case this is undesirable, the application can be switched to production,

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```

at the top of application main module.

Comment: could you please take a look at this example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-86gpc3?file=src%2FApp.js) I've added the line you said to use in the index.js and im printing its content when the App component is rendered, and it says 'production', but the global error handler is still taking over. Please advise

Comment: This should be done above React import. It works in Stackblitz, but If it's not possible in some different setup (imports are hoisted by specs), the line should be moved to separate module and again imported above React import.

Comment: Thanks @Estus, got it working. Now i just have to find a way to test it in development mode.